# Radix Sort - Padding Number Of Digits

Tags: java

I am implementing radix sort algorithm in java and I have encountered with a little problem.
This is the code for countin the number of digits.

```
public int countDigits(int number){  
      int temp=number;
      int digits=0;
      while(temp!=0){
          temp=temp/10;
          digits++;
      }
      return digits; }
```

After counting the number of digits I want to pad the the number with the leading zeroes that are equal to the number of digits returned from the function. I saw one method that was

```
int a = 11;
String with3digits = String.format("%03d", a);
String.out.println(with3digits);
```

But the problem here is using `%03d` as the padding , how can i use a variable here?

Comment: You mean like this? `String.format("%" + padding + "d" ,a);`

Comment: Is this a valid method? If so, yes.